# Java: Multiple sockets send and receive maintain in a single thread

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I am a new java socket developer. In my solution has three sockets for sending and receiving. I want to receive three socket's data in a single thread. For this reason, how i get notification which socket get data from remote.

Answer (score 1):

Handling multiple streams (those of the sockets) within a single thread is possible. It requires the use of socket channels (from java.nio.channels) and of a (single) `Selector.`

You create a Selector and *register* the `SocketChannels.`

To learn about any new possibility for an i/o operation, you call the `Selector`'s `select()` method, which returns whenever one of the channels is ready for reading, writing or accepting. You'll have to learn the ready channel (i.e., obtain its "key"), and call its appropriate data transfer method.

There is some sample code to be found on the net.

PS: It might be easier to use threads.

Comment: @committedandroider Java uses the terms "ServerSocket" for "listening socket" and "Socket" for communication endpoints, also "stream-oriented connecting sockets" (which I tend to call "data sockets").

Comment: No. I want to means that sockets receiving data.